# Switch help NumberPicker Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

So I have 2 string filled Number Pickers but the app to stop forces closing when the NP is turned, ive tried a few things and they all result in the same, never used with string in number pickers before. ill post the error, layout and java below, any help in lovely

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    final NumberPicker letterPicker;
    final NumberPicker monthPicker;
    final ImageView cocktailImage;
    final TextView letterName;
    final TextView monthName;

    letterPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.letterPicker);
    monthPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.monthPicker);
    cocktailImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cocktailImage);
    letterName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.letterName);
    monthName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthName);
    final String[] first = res.getStringArray(R.array.name_letter);
    final String[] second = res.getStringArray(R.array.name_month);
    letterPicker.setMinValue(0);
    letterPicker.setMaxValue(25);

    monthPicker.setMinValue(0);
    monthPicker.setMaxValue(11);


    letterPicker.setDisplayedValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alphabet));
    monthPicker.setDisplayedValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months));



    letterPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            switch (newVal /*this wont work was just testing not sure what to put here*/) {
                case 0:
                    letterName.setText(first[0]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    letterName.setText(first[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    letterName.setText(first[2]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    letterName.setText(first[3]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    letterName.setText(first[4]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    letterName.setText(first[5]);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    letterName.setText(first[6]);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    letterName.setText(first[7]);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    letterName.setText(first[8]);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    letterName.setText(first[9]);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    letterName.setText(first[10]);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    letterName.setText(first[11]);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    letterName.setText(first[12]);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    letterName.setText(first[13]);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    letterName.setText(first[14]);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    letterName.setText(first[15]);
                    break;
                case 16:
                    letterName.setText(first[16]);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    letterName.setText(first[17]);
                    break;
                case 18:
                    letterName.setText(first[18]);
                    break;
                case 19:
                    letterName.setText(first[19]);
                    break;
                case 20:
                    letterName.setText(first[20]);
                    break;
                case 21:
                    letterName.setText(first[21]);
                    break;
                case 22:
                    letterName.setText(first[22]);
                    break;
                case 23:
                    letterName.setText(first[23]);
                    break;
                case 24:
                    letterName.setText(first[24]);
                    break;
                case 25:
                    letterName.setText(first[25]);
                    break;
            }
}
```

With error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
    at com.cocktailname.stephen.cocktailname.MainActivity$1.onValueChange(MainActivity.java:127)
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1879)
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1665)
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1128)
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.onTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:910)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.dispatchTouchEvent(NumberPicker.java:967)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2383)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1724)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2764)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeCo
```

Xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/letterPicker"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:id="@+id/monthPicker"/>
```

String Array First
     -

```
<item>Randy</item>

<item>Sweet</item>

<item>Sexy</item>

<item>Hot</item>

<item>Smokin</item>

<item>Slippery</item>

<item>Gorgeous</item>

<item>Handsome</item>

<item>Leggy</item>

<item>Blonde</item>

<item>Spicy</item>

<item>High</item>

<item>Running</item>

<item>Sucking</item>

<item>Jelly</item>

<item>Frigid</item>

<item>Juicy</item>

<item>Kissing</item>

<item>Sunset</item>

<item>Blazing</item>

<item>Lovely</item>

<item>Spotted</item>

<item>Brass</item>

<item>Dirty</item>

<item>Zombie</item>

<item>Moscow</item>
```

Comment: Post the array that is defined on XML.

Comment: @GeorgeD array is up

Answer (score 0):

In the second switch I was parsing a string to an int, and it didn't like it